# Find out if a constant of given value already exists in Java (with CLI, IntelliJ, etc)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a command line tool, or an IntelliJ feature/plugin that could do this for me:

I would like to use a string `access_denied` somewhere in code, but I know from the docs of a dependency ([like these for example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/constant-values.html)), that is defined as a constant somewhere so of course I use it as `OAuth2ErrorCodes.ACCESS_DENIED`.

Or I know would like to use an Integer of value `404`, and it would automagically inform me that HttpStatusCode.NOT_FOUND already exposes this value?

Comment: in eclipse "Ctrl"+"H" -> file search -> containing text = whatever you want to search -> scope = workspace -> search -> profit

Comment: @XtremeBaumer of course, this would work for source files :) but this won't search compiled (eg. maven) dependencies

Comment: if you want to search in libraries, you use the "Java Search" instead of the "File Search"

Comment: @XtremeBaumer tried this just right now, it is almost perfect, since it searches by field names, and not values

Comment: If you are using Jetty can you maybe get some inspiration from `HttpStatus` class: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.6.v20170531/org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpStatus.html

Comment: @vikingsteve thanks, I assume you mean the naming convention containing values it this class - it is an interesting and helpful approach to, but it is not solving the general problem